# Possible generation bug for C# in Antlr?

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

Using Antlr 4.3 and this grammar

http://www.harward.us/~nharward/antlr/OracleNetServicesV3.g

following *Lexer.cs code for C# is generated :

```
private void WHITESPACE_action(RuleContext _localctx, int actionIndex) {
    switch (actionIndex) {
    case 1: skip(); break;
    }
}

private void NEWLINE_action(RuleContext _localctx, int actionIndex) {
    switch (actionIndex) {
    case 2: skip(); break;
    }
}
private void COMMENT_action(RuleContext _localctx, int actionIndex) {
    switch (actionIndex) {
    case 0: skip(); break;
    }
}
```

But the method skip() in the runtime is defined as:

```
public virtual void Skip()
```

Which of course gives a compilation error.

The same skip() method is generated with Antlr 3.5.2 as well.

Is this a bug or i am doing something wrong?

Comment: That sounds like an ANTLR v3 grammar file.

Comment: Yes indeed i found it. :D The problem is in the grammar file. The rule  COMMENT already has a skip (with lowercase letter)  in it. So the question should be now: How i can build a language independ grammar. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily make this v4 compatible and language independent by using the command

```
-> channel(HIDDEN)
```

Here is an updated grammar that implements this change

```
configuration_file
: ( parameter )*
;

parameter
: keyword EQUALS ( value
                 | LEFT_PAREN value_list RIGHT_PAREN
                 | ( LEFT_PAREN parameter RIGHT_PAREN )+
                 )
;

keyword
: WORD
;

value
: WORD
| QUOTED_STRING
;

value_list
: value ( COMMA value )*
;

QUOTED_STRING
    : SINGLE_QUOTE  ~'\''* SINGLE_QUOTE
    | DOUBLE_QUOTE  ~'"'*  DOUBLE_QUOTE
    ;

WORD
    : ( 'A' .. 'Z'
      | 'a' .. 'z'
      | '0' .. '9'
      | '<'
      | '>'
      | '/'
      | '.'
      | ':'
      | ';'
      | '-'
      | '_'
      | '$'
      | '+'
      | '*'
      | '&'
      | '!'
      | '%'
      | '?'
      | '@'
      | '\\' .
      )+
    ;

LEFT_PAREN
    : '('
    ;

RIGHT_PAREN
    : ')'
    ;

EQUALS
    : '='
    ;

COMMA
    : ','
    ;

SINGLE_QUOTE
    : '\''
    ;

DOUBLE_QUOTE
    : '"'
    ;

COMMENT
    : '#' ( ~( '\n' ) )* -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

WHITESPACE
    : ( '\t'
      | ' '
      )  -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

NEWLINE
    : ( '\r' )? '\n'  -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

Comment: This is true, thank you. Or you can use  "-> skip".  It really helps to read the book (The Definiteive ANTLR 4 Reference).

Comment: A better implementation (at least for my needs) of the grammar for tnsnames.ora files you can find here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tnsnames

Answer (score 0):

As written in my comment, it's because auf the skip() in the grammar file, which is Java dependend.

So there is **no** bug in Antlr. :)